# Adding a <br/> after loop section has ran

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am using the following code.

```
<?php

//DB CONNECTION

$ROWS = "id,firstname,lastname";

// explode at the comma and insert into an array
$test = explode("," , $ROWS);

//adds array test to the var sam
$sam = array($test);

// querys the database
$new = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$DB_TABLE}");

// while loop to loop through selected fields
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($new)) {

    foreach ($sam[0] as $v) {

        echo $row[$v] . $DELIMITER . "<br />";

    }

}
?>
```

I get the following results.

```
834(|)
Steph(|)
Thompson(|)
835(|)
Lucy(|)
kim(|)
836(|)
Iwan(|)
Will(|)
837(|)
Sarah (|)
Good(|)
```

The problem I have is the `<br>` tag. Where do I put it? Because I need it to output like this (like it shows in the $ROWS variable above `$ROWS = "id,firstname,lastname";`)

```
834(|)Step(|)Thompson(|)
835(|)Lucy(|)kim(|)
836(|)Iwan(|)Will(|)
837(|)Sarah (|)Good(|)
```

Where do I add the `<br>` tag?

Comment: Immediately after the foreach... Now close it yourself because it's not a real question.

Comment: @alin why not real question???

Comment: @diEcho Because of this "Thanks feel super dumb now haha cheers for your help diecho".

Comment: @diEcho Also because one of the criteria to close a question is: **too localized:** This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Comment: @Alin: WTF? How is this localized? It's dumb but it's not localized.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal "extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet" - Do you see yourself asking this question, or a similar one somewhere in the future? Do you think people will find this page searching with a search engine?

Comment: @Alin: Meh. I don't think it fits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($new)) {
    foreach ($sam[0] as $v) {
        echo $row[$v] . $DELIMITER;
    }
      echo "<br />";

}
```